# img.width and img.height randomly returns 0

Tags: javascript, html

Thanks to existing threads, I was able to come up with the following code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = imgSrc;
if(imgSrc.substring(imgSrcLength-4, imgSrcLength) == '.ico'){
    document.getElementById('size' + lineCount).innerHTML = img.height + 'x' + img.width;
} else {
    document.getElementById('size' + lineCount).innerHTML = img.naturalHeight + 'x' + img.naturalWidth;
}
```

You can basically ignore the lineCount part. It just should display the size of different Images in an html list. However sometimes the width or height is returned as 0. For me it appears to be random since if I run the script again the right amount will be loaded and some other place is 0. If I try to debug the code via the Microsoft Edge function everything works fine and there won't be any 0.

Is this a problem caused by my Microsoft Edge or did I miss out onto something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the image to finish loading and then get it's size. Try it like that:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    if(imgSrc.substring(imgSrcLength-4, imgSrcLength) == '.ico'){
        document.getElementById('size' + lineCount).innerHTML = img.height + 'x' + img.width;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('size' + lineCount).innerHTML = img.naturalHeight + 'x' + img.naturalWidth;
    }
};
img.src = imgSrc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the image returns 0 for width and height when it is not loaded while the code is evaluated. Please make sure that the image is loaded before running your code (i.e. by running the code in the onLoad event for window).